# Getting SSRS to display just the specified print message?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

How to show output of print message from sql in ssrs report. Is it Possible in SSRS?
I am selecting data from Table when no row exist it prints No data in sql query editor.
I want to pass print message 'No Data' to ssrs Report.

Answer (score 0):

You can use and expression

```
=IIF(Count(<SomeId Field>,"DataSet1")=0,"No Data Returned", nothing)
```

This should return your message if there is 0 count or no data.